# Create Separate Portrait and Landscape Layouts for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I am working on an iPhone app and I want to create separate layouts for Portrait view and Landscape View.  In Portrait layout I have 2 columns with 3 rows of square buttons (this is done with a xib in interface builder).  In Landscape I would like to have 3 columns with 2 rows.  Is this possible?  I have added the following code that I thought might work for this.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:    
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
    toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    NSLog(@"Landscape Rotation Occurred");
    scriptureButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 130, 130);
    characterSketchButton.frame = CGRectMake(170, 20, 130, 130);
    mapButton.frame = CGRectMake(320, 20, 130, 130);
    storyingButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 170, 130, 130);
    videoButton.frame = CGRectMake(170, 170, 130, 130);
    otherResourcesButton.frame = CGRectMake(320, 170, 130, 130);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Portrait Rotation Occurred");
    scriptureButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 130, 130);
    characterSketchButton.frame = CGRectMake(170, 20, 130, 130);
    mapButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 170, 130, 130);
    storyingButton.frame = CGRectMake(170, 170, 130, 130);
    videoButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 320, 130, 130);
    otherResourcesButton.frame = CGRectMake(170, 320, 130, 130);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are generally two approaches to implementing this manually --

1. Position your views yourself as your code does. There's nothing inherently bad about it, but note it would need to be done in view's (not view controller's) `layoutSubviews`. Any frame that you set before view lays out its subviews will be reset in the process by autolayout.
2. Have two controllers and have e.g. The portrait one automatically show and dismiss the landscape one on transition.

Since you can use all niceties of autolayout and interface builder to model as usual in the second method, this is generally considered preferred.

Although you can also use a variant of 1, by changing not the frames directly, but rather the layout constraints on the view if for some reason two-controller solution is unacceptable.

However, from your question it actually sounds like you need a `UICollectionView`. Once you set the cell size it will reposition its cells as necessary during the view controller's bounds changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I went Collection View, something I had considered before.